# Java Substance look and feel problem

Tags: java, look-and-feel, substance

I have a problem with substance look and feel. I'm trying to set Office 2007 LAF as descibed [here](https://substance.dev.java.net/docs/skins/toneddown.html#OfficeBlue2007Skin).

```
    try
    {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("org.pushingpixels.substance.api.skin.SubstanceOfficeBlue2007LookAndFeel");
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception:"+ ex.getMessage());
    }
```

But when i run this code I get exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/pushingpixels/trident/ease/TimelineEase

What am I doing wrong? Anybody have experience with substance LAF?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It'd seem that you need the [Trident library](http://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home) in order to use Substance. Grab it and stick it in your classpath and it should work.

Comment: thanks! it works. By why it can't work without this library? Why substance distributes without this library?

Comment: No idea :). It is listed on the substance download page: https://substance.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=11795, but that seems to be about it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok... here goes... http://insubstantial.github.com/insubstantial/

Download your JAR from there

Answer (score 0):

Looks like corresponding JAR file is missing in your application classpath.
I am not very sure of the JAR file name.... but look out for any JAR named *substance* on your desktop and try and add that to your classpath.

Isn't org.pushingpixels provide any download link to the Substance L&F JAR? Try that too....

Lemme know if that helped...